# PayPal REST API Getting 422 Unprocessable Entity Error using Sandbox Account

Tags: javascript, api, rest, paypal, sdk

I'm making an e-commerce application and I'm using the JavaScript SDK. When I create an order WITH the items list, I get the 422 error. When I create it without the items list, it works like a charm. However, I need to be able to list out all of the items from my cart in the items list. Can anyone help me?

Here's the documenation to create an order: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

This works:

```
return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
            value: '9.99'
        }
    }]
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
var items = [];
for (const i of shoppingCart) {
    items.push({
        'name': `${i.length}" ${i.name} ${i.category}`,
        'unit_amount': {
            currency_code: 'USD',
            value: '9.99'
        },
        'quantity': '2'
    })
}

return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
            value: '{{ grandTotal }}'
        },
        items: items
    }]
});
```

Solved. Here's a full solution of what I needed to do:

```
purchase_units: [
    {
        amount: {
            value: '{{ grandTotal }}',
            currency_code: 'USD',
            breakdown: {
                item_total: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: '{{ total }}'
                },
                discount: {
                    currency_code: 'USD',
                    value: discount
                }
            }
        },
        items: items
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the message text of the 422 error's response, which you can obtain from the dev tools console or Network tab? The response text contains a details object with a description field that will tell you what you are missing.

Well, you are missing an `amount.breakdown.item_total` subtotal, which per the v2/checkout/orders API is required when passing an `items` array with amounts: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown

A simple example:

```
// based on example array from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/
  "purchase_units": [{
      "amount": {
        "value": "17.17",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "17.17"
          },
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "17.17"
          },
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "item 1",
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
```